# Making tables with \multicolumn

Tags: tables

I've made the following table using `\multicolumn`. Everything looks fine. Unfortunately when I replace A, B or C with some longer text, I get unequal spacing between the three columns below. Can anyone explain me why?

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|ccc|ccc|ccc|c|}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{3}{|c}{Longer text} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{C} &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{D} \\
    \midrule 
    a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}\\
     a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
\cline{1-9}
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
\cline{1-9}
     a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
     a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please post a full example, not just fragments. Apparently, you're using `booktabs`?

Comment: Tabular environment stretches the space to fit the content. If you don't want this, you should specify the width, for instance with `p{1cm}` instead of `c`.

Answer (score 3):

Some propositions: Remove the vertical lines and use a `C{0.3cm}` etc. columntype in conjunction with the `*{3}C{}` repetition codes, to ease the use of such column beasts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
\newlength{\stdcolumnwidth}
\setlength{\stdcolumnwidth}{0.3cm}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{C{\stdcolumnwidth}}*{3}{C{\stdcolumnwidth}}*{3}{C{\stdcolumnwidth}}c}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Longer text} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} &D \\
    \midrule 
    a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c & \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c & \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} &  \\
    \midrule
    a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c &  \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\
    a & b & c & a & b & c & a & b & c &  \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arise when the  width of text in `multicolumn` cell is wider than sum of longest text of belonging columns (see figure below). In this case first two columns have natural width, but third one accommodate its width to width requested by `multicolum` cell.

This problem can be solved on different ways, among them the following two are relative simple, however both require manual tweaking of columns width. In both the table columns are divided into groups (as suggest Christian Hupfer in his answer). With this you have the columns width in the columns, where arise your problem. Proposed solutions are:

- you adjust width of columns in the group where the your problem arise for amount, that widths of all belonging columns are equal
- make text in `multicolumn` cell narrower with breaking it into more lines so, that it can be fit in available width for `multicolum` cell.
- of course, both aforementioned approach can be combined in searching a compromise for better looks of table

The problem and first two mentioned solution illustrate MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\theadset{\normalsize\renewcommand\arraystretch{.85}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

    \begin{document}
    \centering
demonstrate the problem\\
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{C{4mm}|}*{3}{C{4mm}|}*{3}{C{4mm}|}c|}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Longer text}
            &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{BBBB BBB BB BBBBB}
                            &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C}
                                            & D   \\
    \midrule
a & b & c   & a & b & c     & a & b & c     &     \\
1 & 2 & 3   & 1 & 2 & 3     & 1 & 2 & 3     & 4   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
first possible solution\\
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{C{4mm}|}*{3}{C{10mm}|}*{3}{C{4mm}|}c|}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Longer text}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{BBBB BBB BB BBBBB}
                            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C}
                                            & D   \\
    \midrule
a & b & c   & a & b & c     & a & b & c     &     \\
1 & 2 & 3   & 1 & 2 & 3     & 1 & 2 & 3     & 4   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
second possible solution\\
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{C{4mm}|}*{3}{C{4mm}|}*{3}{C{4mm}|}c|}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Longer text}
            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\thead[b]{BBBB BBB\\ BB BBBBB}}
                            & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{C}
                                            & D   \\
    \midrule
a & b & c   & a & b & c     & a & b & c     &     \\
1 & 2 & 3   & 1 & 2 & 3     & 1 & 2 & 3     & 4   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Package `makecell` is added for second solution, where is used macro `thead` from this package. For illustration I consider only first three rows from table.

[image]